# Give the user a paid in app purchase for free

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to work out how I can give the user 1 free in app purchase when they first download and run the app. Ive found a way to make sure they can only do it once but I can't seem to figure out how to give them a paid one for free?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to just skip in-app purchase the first time and log it using `NSUserDefaults` or something.